# Github desktop pushes to remote origin but fetch fails

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am having an issue with GitHub Desktop. For some reason, I am able to successfully push my changes to my remote origin but each time I do, I get this error message, telling me it was unable to *fetch* from origin.

From https://github.com/my-company-organization/my-repo

- [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/HEAD 2
  fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 2
  error: https://github.com/my-company-organization/my-repo.git did not send all necessary objects

I've checked to see if my remote origin is correctly set up by running git remote -v in the command line and it looks correct to me:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/my-company-organization/my-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/my-company-organization/my-repo.git (push)
```

However, if I try pushing using the command line, I get this error:`remote: Repository not found.`

This is the second time this has happened to me in the last couple of days and the way I initially fixed it was by deleting my repo locally and cloning it again from GitHub.

Now that it has happened again I would like to see if someone else has had this issue and how did they solve it because I wouldn't like to have to delete it and clone it again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are cloning to iCloud Drive or Google drive or similar, aren't you? If so, don't.

Comment: @matt actually yes, I realized now that my desktop is in my iCloud Drive. Can you please explain why this has an effect?

BTW I got help from a friend and she helped me fix it by running rm ".git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD" and rm ".git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 2" which removed both HEAD and HEAD 2

Comment: The problem will simply recur, just as it already has. You need to get this repo out from under the control of iCloud Drive.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788975/bitbucket-git-error-did-not-send-all-necessary-objects. Closing as a duplicate.